# I/O expanders- CAN & I2C

Tags: i2c, communication, can, interface

Currently in my system we use 16 I/O expanders with I2C interface. I want to change it to CAN interface. Which is the best possible way without compromising the cost? 
I tried searching for 16I/O expanders with CAN interface but the maximum I could get is 8I/O. 
Are there any CAN to I2C converters, If yes I can use the same I/O expanders, just put a converter before.

Also looking for ADC with CAN interface!

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the best possible way without compromising the cost?

Your cost will go up, if you want to replace I<sup>2</sup>C with CAN.  An I/O expander with CAN interface is "simply" a microcontroller with a CAN interface.  A bridge between CAN and I<sup>2</sup>C is also a microcontroller with a CAN interface.  So, you are looking at a cost of a CAN bus driver IC, cost of a microcontroller itself (maybe with a crystal), labor cost of programming that microcontroller.

Having said that, [I do understand why replacing an overextended I<sup>2</sup>C](http://www.prolifictec.com/blog/2014/11/memoirs-of-overgrown-i2c-bus.html) with CAN may be a right idea.

As a side benefit, you can have a degree of local control and processing at the periphery.  Plus lots of useful peripherals which come on microcontrollers.

Comment: I understand the cost will go up. But are there any 16 I/O expanders with CAN interface in market? Also is ADC's with CAN interface available?

Comment: A microcontroller with CAN interface and 16x GPIO is your I/O expander.  Same with ADC.  Microcontrollers with CAN, 16x GPIO, ADC are on the market alright.  You are unlikely to find canned [pun semi-intended] or hard-wired CAN I/O expanders or ADCs on the market, because different industries run different network protocols, on top of CAN physical layer.  Such network protocols are a lot more varied than I2C.  [If you find canned devices like that, those are exceptions.]

Comment: @Ashok The key is that CAN is intended for relatively long ranges in rugged environments, while I/O expanders with I2C are intended for on-board or short range communication in "nice" environments. So none make expander IC for CAN because there's likely not much of a market for it. You can find plenty of higher level DIN rail I/O stuff using CANopen though, complete with supply and output drivers. So this is probably where you need to step back and look at the bigger picture - what is your product supposed to do and what's the requirements.

Comment: That's correct! Is it possible for a CAN to I2C converter IC so that I2C enabled expanders and ADC can be used, which is readily available also.